# struts2 jquery from date and to date

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I am working a webproject using struts2 and I used struts2 jquery plugin for datepicker.
Now I need to validate **ToDate** depending on **FromDate**.
**ToDate** shouldnot be greater than **FromDate**

validation should be like this, datepicker should disable the behind dates accodring to fromdate.Then user not able to select lower than the from date

Please let me know how can I implemt this.
Please post the code will help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's your choice how you want to impliment the validation.There are 2 ways which as of now seems feasible to me

1. Client side validation using JavaScript.
2. Server Side validation in your action class.

For the first part your both data-picker must have id and name so once user filled `ToDate` and `FromDate` and before submitting the form you can call a java-script function where you can fetch the values of respective date-picker fields using java-script `document.getEmelemntById()` and can run your comparison logic.

Other option is to let Struts2 fill the `ToDate` and `FromDate` values in your action class and you can use `validate` method inside your Action to perform date validation.choice is all yours.

You can even play around with validation framework even.

**Update**

After playing around with J query plugin source code here is the workaround we have

```
 <s:form id="form" theme="xhtml">
    <sj:datepicker id="date12" name="date12" label="With Close Event" onCompleteTopics="onDpClose"/>
    <sj:datepicker id="date13" name="date13" label="With Min and Max Date" minDate="0" maxDate="+2m"/>
    </s:form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $.subscribe('onDpClose', function(event,data) {
        $('#date13').datepicker( "option" , 'minDate',event.originalEvent.dateText ); 
     });
   </script>
```

In similar way can work for other way around.Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Not like this,I want datepicker should disable  the behind dates accodring to fromdate.Then user not able to select lower than the from date

Comment: aha it was not there earlier :)

Comment: yes I have updated my question sorry for this ,I have not stated the question  properly. Please let me know how I can implement

Comment: @naveen: though i never used this plugin as i never felt comfortable with it but going through there doc i came across `mindate` and `maxdate` attribute and i guess that will server your purpose

Comment: [showcase](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action). they have example with With Min and Max Date and have disabled the things according..all you need to set these values as per your need

Comment: They are fixing the min and max date in field itself.I want to set the min date   dynimcally for Todate depending on the fromdate selected.ToDate min date should greater than the from date.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6180/discussion-between-umesh-awasthi-and-naveen)

Comment: ALWAYS validate at server-side. Don't rely on JavaScript validation: it can be disabled or circumvented. JavaScript validation is a bonus, but server-side validation is mandatory.

Comment: The given solution is working fine.For my case I need some workaround need to do. thanks once again for this.

Comment: @JBNizet:Op need is more related to display purpose and i am agree server-side validation is must

Answer (score 0):

There is an example similar to what you ask for on [datepicker demos site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range).

I've modified and tried to simplify that example and created a fiddle for it which you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/melih/vRULq/